# Stored procedure to check if category parent exist

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I’m having a problem with a C# MVC project in ASP.NET.
The problem I have is with a category system: If one category has been added to a company, then you should not be able to add any category that is a parent (higher level in the hierarchy) than what’s already been added (since it’s already included in the search).

Now I have added this in the C# code already using this:

```
if (companyToUpdate.Category.Any(x => x.Parent.Any(z => z.ID == currentCategoryID))) {
    //already exists
}
```

Now the problem is that I would like to add this check as a stored procedure in the SQL Server database.

My structure looks like this:

**Company (all companies)**

```
 ID Title
1   StackOverflow
```

**Category (all categories)**

```
 ID Title
1   Website
2   Helpful site
3   Very helpful site
```

**CategoryDetails (used to know parent/child of each category,
    every category has a relationship to all of its parents)
    (Website -> Helpful site -> Very helpful site)**

```
Parent_ID   Child_ID
1           2
1           3
2           3
```

**CompanyCategoryDetails (what categories have been added to this company?)**

```
 Company_ID Category_ID
1           3
```

Now to the problem:
When you are trying to add a new line (1, 2) into CompanyCategoryDetails, it should be denied, since because you have already added Category_ID 3 to it, that means Category_ID 2 is already included which specified in the CategoryDetails table.

I started doing some check where I INNERJOIN the tables, but didnt get far before I realized it couldnt be done the way I was thinking.

Comment: Are you stuck with the `CategoryDetails` table, or could it be redesigned if it will make queries like this more straightforward?

Comment: Do you mean that if you have 1,2 then you shouldn't be allowed to add 1,3, rather than the reverse that you have asked?

Comment: If you have 1,2 then you should be able to add 1,3 because 1,3 would be more specific than 1,2. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the check you are asking for is this:

```
IF EXISTS(
SELECT * 
FROM    CompanyCategoryDetails CCD
JOIN    CategoryDetails CD
        ON  CCD.Category_ID = CD.Child_ID
WHERE   CCD.Company_ID = @Company_ID
AND     (CD.Parent_ID = @Category_ID OR CD.Child_ID = @Category_ID))
BEGIN
    --already exists
END
```

This will check for trying to add to a compnay (a) a parent category or (b) an existing category

Comment: Hi! The final solution I was looking for was very similar to this, so I'm accepting this answer. Thanks for your help!